# would be possible to change the layout of suggested questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, style

I find the layout of the "Questions that may already have your answer" a bit confusing. I'm wondering if it might be a good idea to restyle it a bit.

This is the current layout with my notes:

[image]

This might be a more readable solution:

[image]

- the title is more prominent
- circles instead of squares for consistency
- answers with accepted replies on top
- removed the number of answers from the right

The hover popup could be styled better, too, as it is now is very hard to read.

Also instead of showing the scrollbar when there are many results I think it might be better to paginate the results ordering by relevance with the replied/closed answers always on top.

Comment: and please, order them by votes and if they have upvoted/accepted answers! BTW, now that I have a static image, aren't the boxes no aligned in the right?

Comment: that box is a bit of a mess imho, that might be a reason why we get so many duplicates

Comment: @Braiam Ordering them first by votes would be bad. Right now, the system makes some attempt to show answers that are good search results for the title text. Ordering "Questions that may already have your answer" by votes would ensure that most of the time, none of the questions shown have anything to do with what the new OP is asking. Putting answers with accepted replies first would be bad in a similar way, though to a lesser degree.

Comment: @EliahKagan well right now the system is pretty broken even doing that. Try as title "How to install Ubuntu", then try "how do i install ubuntu", you will see abysmal differences between each of the titles, and is probably one of the main reasons why the search is broken and we get all those dupes (in fact dupes should show the parent question and play in the search order too). The first doesn't give relevant questions, and the second even give non related to the title.

Comment: @Braiam That's true. I think the whole Stack Exchange search infrastructure needs work. I often use Google or DuckDuckGo to find things here.

Comment: @EliahKagan I think the solution would be to paginate by relevance. So in page 1 you have the first 5 results with the highest relevance sorted by number of answers/votes/accepted answer. On page 2 you get results with slightly less relevant always ordered by votes/etc.. And so on.

Comment: @EliahKagan Yeah, like the duplicate close vote queue.. If I don't type in the master question's "exact" title it comes up with all sorts of awful suggestions..

Comment: @Seth I was meaning to post this sooner or later: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7293/how-do-i-quickly-find-the-duplicate-questions-when-flagging-closing

Comment: @Alaa Awesome!!